# Optimizing an Oracle Query

Tags: oracle11g

I have created a query that usually takes 7 to 11 secs to return a set and I want to make this faster. I understand that I have to make use if indexes for for this to happen so I have properly made use of them. Unfortunately, it will give out the same execution time: Here is the query that I use:

```
WITH trackin8080 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c.containerid
    , c.containername
    , hml.historyid
    , hml.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
    , hml.qty
    , hml.txndate
  FROM CONTAINER c  
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      MAX(wwl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid) OVER (PARTITION BY wwl.containerid) wiptrackiggroupkeyid
      , wwl.containerid
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        , wl.containerid
      FROM a_wiplot wl
      WHERE wl.specname IN ('8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT')
      AND wl.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND wl.containername LIKE :lotid AND wl.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%'

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        , wl.containerid
      FROM a_wiplothistory wl
      WHERE wl.specname IN ('8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT')
      AND wl.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND wl.containername LIKE :lotid AND wl.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
    )wwl
    GROUP BY wwl.containerid, wwl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
  )wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
  JOIN historymainline hml ON c.containerid = hml.historyid AND hml.cdoname = 'TrackInLot' AND hml.specname IN ('8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT') AND wl.wiptrackiggroupkeyid = hml.wiptrackinggroupkeyid --AND hml.txndate > TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7)
  WHERE hml.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND c.containername LIKE :lotid
), trackout8080 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c.containerid
    , c.containername
    , hml.historyid
    , hml.historymainlineid
    , hml.txndate
    , hml.qty
  FROM trackin8080 ti
  INNER JOIN container c ON ti.containerid = c.containerid
  INNER JOIN product p ON c.productid = p.productid
  INNER JOIN historymainline hml ON c.containerid = hml.historyid AND hml.cdoname = 'TrackOutLot' AND hml.specname IN ('8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT')
  WHERE hml.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND c.containername LIKE :lotid
), movein8527 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c.containerid
    , c.containername
    , hml.historyid
    , hml.historymainlineid
    , hml.txndate
    , hml.shiftname
    , hml.employeeid
    , hml.qty
    , p.device
    , p.brandname
    , hml.specname
    , hml.comments
  FROM trackin8080 ti
  INNER JOIN container c ON ti.containerid = c.containerid
  INNER JOIN product p ON c.productid = p.productid
  INNER JOIN historymainline hml ON c.containerid = hml.historyid
  WHERE (hml.callbycdoname IN ('TestWIPMain', 'TestWIPMoveNonStd') AND hml.cdoname = 'MoveInLot' AND hml.specname IN ('8527_STAGE_BAKE_FT'))
  AND hml.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND c.containername LIKE :lotid
), moveout8925 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c.containerid
    , c.containername
    , hml.historyid
    , hml.historymainlineid
    , hml.txndate
    , hml.shiftname
    , hml.employeeid
    , hml.qty
    , p.device
    , p.brandname
    , hml.specname
    , hml.comments
  FROM trackin8080 ti
  INNER JOIN container c ON ti.containerid = c.containerid
  INNER JOIN product p ON c.productid = p.productid
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      MAX(wwl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid) OVER (PARTITION BY wwl.containerid) wiptrackiggroupkeyid
      , wwl.containerid
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        , wl.containerid
      FROM a_wiplot wl
      WHERE wl.specname IN ('8925_2ND_RM_TST_SOT_2_FT')
      AND wl.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND wl.containername LIKE :lotid AND wl.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%'

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        , wl.containerid
      FROM a_wiplothistory wl
      WHERE wl.specname IN ('8925_2ND_RM_TST_SOT_2_FT')
      AND wl.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND wl.containername LIKE :lotid AND wl.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
    )wwl
    GROUP BY wwl.containerid, wwl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
  )wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
  INNER JOIN historymainline hml ON c.containerid = hml.historyid AND wl.wiptrackiggroupkeyid = hml.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
  WHERE (hml.callbycdoname IN ('LotMoveOut', 'MoveLot', 'TestWIPMoveNonStd') AND hml.cdoname = 'CreateFirstInsertion' AND hml.specname IN ('8925_2ND_RM_TST_SOT_2_FT'))
  AND hml.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND c.containername LIKE :lotid
), trackin8090 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c.containerid
    , c.containername
    , hml.historyid
    , hml.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
    , hml.qty
    , hml.txndate
  FROM CONTAINER c  
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      MAX(wwl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid) OVER (PARTITION BY wwl.containerid) wiptrackiggroupkeyid
      , wwl.containerid
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        , wl.containerid
      FROM a_wiplot wl
      WHERE wl.specname IN ('8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT')
      AND wl.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND wl.containername LIKE :lotid AND wl.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%'

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        , wl.containerid
      FROM a_wiplothistory wl
      WHERE wl.specname IN ('8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT')
      AND wl.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND wl.containername LIKE :lotid AND wl.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
    )wwl
    GROUP BY wwl.containerid, wwl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
  )wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
  JOIN historymainline hml ON c.containerid = hml.historyid AND hml.cdoname = 'TrackInLot' AND hml.specname IN ('8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT') AND wl.wiptrackiggroupkeyid = hml.wiptrackinggroupkeyid --AND hml.txndate > TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7)
  WHERE hml.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND c.containername LIKE :lotid
), trackout8090 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c.containerid
    , c.containername
    , hml.historyid
    , hml.historymainlineid
    , hml.txndate
    , hml.qty
  FROM trackin8080 ti
  INNER JOIN container c ON ti.containerid = c.containerid
  INNER JOIN product p ON c.productid = p.productid
  INNER JOIN historymainline hml ON c.containerid = hml.historyid AND hml.cdoname = 'TrackOutLot' AND hml.specname IN ('8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT')
  WHERE hml.workflowname IN ('6_2B2R-DP_WIP') AND c.containername LIKE :lotid
)

SELECT
  ti8080.containername
  , ti8080.qty qtyatb1
  , to_char(ti8080.txndate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') trackindateb1
  , to_char(ti8080.txndate + 12/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') FCSTDOvenOutB1
  , NVL(to_char(to8080.txndate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'), '-') trackoutdateb1
  , CASE WHEN to8080.txndate IS NULL THEN
      '-'
    ELSE
      to_char(ROUND((to8080.txndate - ti8080.txndate) * 24, 4))
    END AS elapsedtimebake1
  , NVL(to_char(mi8527.qty), '-') qtyatstaging
  , NVL(to_char(mi8527.txndate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'), '-') moveinto8527
  , NVL(to_char(mi8527.txndate + 24/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'), '-') FCSTDEndDate
  , NVL(to_char(mo8925.txndate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'), '-') moveoutto8925
  , CASE WHEN mo8925.txndate IS NULL THEN
      '-'
    ELSE
      to_char(ROUND((mo8925.txndate - mi8527.txndate) * 24, 4))
    END AS elapsedtimestage
  , NVL(to_char(ti8090.qty), '-') qtyatb2
  , NVL(to_char(ti8090.txndate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'), '-') trackindateb2
  , CASE WHEN ti8090.txndate IS NULL THEN
      '-'
    ELSE
      to_char(ti8090.txndate + 24/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
    END AS FCSTDOvenOutB2
  , NVL(to_char(to8090.txndate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'), '-') trackoutdateb2
  , CASE WHEN to8090.txndate IS NULL THEN
      '-'
    ELSE
      to_char(ROUND((to8090.txndate - ti8090.txndate) * 24, 4))
    END AS elapsedtimebake2
FROM trackin8080 ti8080
LEFT JOIN trackout8080 to8080 ON ti8080.containerid = to8080.containerid AND to8080.txndate >= ti8080.txndate
LEFT JOIN movein8527 mi8527 ON ti8080.containerid = mi8527.containerid AND mi8527.txndate >= to8080.txndate
LEFT JOIN moveout8925 mo8925 ON ti8080.containerid = mo8925.containerid AND mo8925.txndate >= mi8527.txndate
LEFT JOIN trackin8090 ti8090 ON ti8080.containerid = ti8090.containerid AND ti8090.txndate >= mi8527.txndate
LEFT JOIN trackout8090 to8090 ON ti8080.containerid = to8090.containerid AND to8090.txndate >= ti8090.txndate
WHERE ti8080.containername LIKE :lotid AND ti8080.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND trunc(ti8080.txndate) > TRUNC(SYSDATE-7)
ORDER BY ti8080.containername
```

And the explain plan:

```
| Id  | Operation                                   | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                            |                             |     1 |   149 | 51140   (1)| 00:10:14 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION                  |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT                            | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DE946_81931B5A |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE                              |                             |     1 |    98 | 17000   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|   4 |     VIEW                                    |                             |     1 |    98 | 16999   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                           |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                          |                             |     1 |   119 | 16999   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|   7 |        VIEW                                 |                             |     1 |    47 | 16964   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |     1 |    64 | 16964   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  10 |           VIEW                              |                             |     1 |    35 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  11 |            WINDOW BUFFER                    |                             |     1 |    34 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  12 |             SORT GROUP BY                   |                             |     1 |    34 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  13 |              VIEW                           |                             |     2 |    68 | 16961   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  14 |               UNION-ALL                     |                             |       |       |            |          |
|* 15 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL            | A_WIPLOT                    |     1 |    87 |   274   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|* 16 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL            | A_WIPLOTHISTORY             |     1 |    81 | 16688   (1)| 00:03:21 |
|* 17 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | CONTAINER450                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | CONTAINER                   |     1 |    29 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | HISTORYMAINLINE2            |    46 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | HISTORYMAINLINE             |     1 |    72 |    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |   SORT ORDER BY                             |                             |     1 |   149 | 34140   (1)| 00:06:50 |
|* 22 |    HASH JOIN OUTER                          |                             |     1 |   149 | 34139   (1)| 00:06:50 |
|  23 |     VIEW                                    |                             |     1 |   123 | 34096   (1)| 00:06:50 |
|* 24 |      HASH JOIN OUTER                        |                             |     1 |   160 | 34096   (1)| 00:06:50 |
|* 25 |       HASH JOIN OUTER                       |                             |     1 |   120 | 17094   (1)| 00:03:26 |
|  26 |        VIEW                                 |                             |     1 |    93 |    88   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|* 27 |         HASH JOIN OUTER                     |                             |     1 |   111 |    88   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|  28 |          VIEW                               |                             |     1 |    71 |    45   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |           HASH JOIN OUTER                   |                             |     1 |    89 |    45   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |            VIEW                             |                             |     1 |    62 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL               | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DE946_81931B5A |     1 |    66 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |            VIEW                             |                             |     1 |    27 |    42   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  33 |             HASH UNIQUE                     |                             |     1 |   161 |    42   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  34 |              NESTED LOOPS                   |                             |       |       |            |          |
|  35 |               NESTED LOOPS                  |                             |     1 |   161 |    41   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |                NESTED LOOPS                 |                             |     1 |    80 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  37 |                 NESTED LOOPS                |                             |     1 |    63 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  38 |                  VIEW                       |                             |     1 |    17 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  39 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL         | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DE946_81931B5A |     1 |    66 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CONTAINER                   |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 41 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | CONTAINER450                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PRODUCT502                  |     1 |    17 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 43 |                INDEX RANGE SCAN             | HISTORYMAINLINE2            |    46 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 44 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | HISTORYMAINLINE             |     1 |    81 |    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  45 |          VIEW                               |                             |     1 |    40 |    43   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  46 |           HASH UNIQUE                       |                             |     1 |   228 |    43   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  47 |            NESTED LOOPS                     |                             |       |       |            |          |
|  48 |             NESTED LOOPS                    |                             |     1 |   228 |    42   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  49 |              NESTED LOOPS                   |                             |     1 |    99 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  50 |               NESTED LOOPS                  |                             |     1 |    63 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  51 |                VIEW                         |                             |     1 |    17 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  52 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DE946_81931B5A |     1 |    66 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 53 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | CONTAINER                   |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 54 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | CONTAINER450                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  55 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PRODUCT                     |     1 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 56 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PRODUCT502                  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 57 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN               | HISTORYMAINLINE2            |    46 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 58 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | HISTORYMAINLINE             |     1 |   129 |    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  59 |        VIEW                                 |                             |     1 |    27 | 17006   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|  60 |         HASH UNIQUE                         |                             |     1 |   271 | 17006   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|* 61 |          HASH JOIN                          |                             |     1 |   271 | 17005   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|  62 |           NESTED LOOPS                      |                             |       |       |            |          |
|  63 |            NESTED LOOPS                     |                             |     1 |   236 |    42   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  64 |             NESTED LOOPS                    |                             |     1 |    99 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  65 |              NESTED LOOPS                   |                             |     1 |    63 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  66 |               VIEW                          |                             |     1 |    17 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  67 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DE946_81931B5A |     1 |    66 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 68 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | CONTAINER                   |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 69 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | CONTAINER450                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  70 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | PRODUCT                     |     1 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 71 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PRODUCT502                  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 72 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                | HISTORYMAINLINE2            |    46 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 73 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | HISTORYMAINLINE             |     1 |   137 |    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  74 |           VIEW                              |                             |     1 |    35 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  75 |            WINDOW BUFFER                    |                             |     1 |    34 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  76 |             SORT GROUP BY                   |                             |     1 |    34 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  77 |              VIEW                           |                             |     2 |    68 | 16961   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  78 |               UNION-ALL                     |                             |       |       |            |          |
|* 79 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL            | A_WIPLOT                    |     1 |    87 |   274   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|* 80 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL            | A_WIPLOTHISTORY             |     1 |    81 | 16688   (1)| 00:03:21 |
|  81 |       VIEW                                  |                             |     1 |    40 | 17001   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|  82 |        HASH UNIQUE                          |                             |     1 |   136 | 17001   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|  83 |         NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |       |       |            |          |
|  84 |          NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |     1 |   136 | 17000   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|  85 |           NESTED LOOPS                      |                             |     1 |    64 | 16964   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  86 |            VIEW                             |                             |     1 |    35 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  87 |             WINDOW BUFFER                   |                             |     1 |    34 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  88 |              SORT GROUP BY                  |                             |     1 |    34 | 16962   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  89 |               VIEW                          |                             |     2 |    68 | 16961   (1)| 00:03:24 |
|  90 |                UNION-ALL                    |                             |       |       |            |          |
|* 91 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL           | A_WIPLOT                    |     1 |    87 |   274   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|* 92 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL           | A_WIPLOTHISTORY             |     1 |    81 | 16688   (1)| 00:03:21 |
|* 93 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | CONTAINER                   |     1 |    29 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 94 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | CONTAINER450                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 95 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | HISTORYMAINLINE2            |    46 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 96 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | HISTORYMAINLINE             |     1 |    72 |    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  97 |     VIEW                                    |                             |     1 |    26 |    42   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  98 |      HASH UNIQUE                            |                             |     1 |   161 |    42   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  99 |       NESTED LOOPS                          |                             |       |       |            |          |
| 100 |        NESTED LOOPS                         |                             |     1 |   161 |    41   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 101 |         NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |     1 |    80 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 102 |          NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |     1 |    63 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 103 |           VIEW                              |                             |     1 |    17 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 104 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL                | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DE946_81931B5A |     1 |    66 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*105 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | CONTAINER                   |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*106 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | CONTAINER450                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*107 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | PRODUCT502                  |     1 |    17 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*108 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | HISTORYMAINLINE2            |    46 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*109 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | HISTORYMAINLINE             |     1 |    81 |    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

  15 - filter("WL"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "WL"."SPECNAME"='8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT' AND 
              "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" IS NOT NULL)
  16 - filter("WL"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "WL"."SPECNAME"='8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT' AND 
              "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" IS NOT NULL)
  17 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="WL"."CONTAINERID")
  18 - filter("C"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID)
  19 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="HML"."HISTORYID")
  20 - filter("HML"."WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID" IS NOT NULL AND "HML"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND 
              "HML"."SPECNAME"='8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT' AND "HML"."CDONAME"='TrackInLot' AND 
              "WL"."WIPTRACKIGGROUPKEYID"="HML"."WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID")
  22 - access("TI8080"."CONTAINERID"="TO8090"."CONTAINERID"(+))
       filter("TO8090"."TXNDATE"(+)>="TI8090"."TXNDATE")
  24 - access("from$_subquery$_054"."QCSJ_C000000005200000"="TI8090"."CONTAINERID"(+))
       filter("TI8090"."TXNDATE"(+)>="from$_subquery$_054"."TXNDATE")
  25 - access("TI8080"."CONTAINERID"="MO8925"."CONTAINERID"(+))
       filter("MO8925"."TXNDATE"(+)>="MI8527"."TXNDATE")
  27 - access("TI8080"."CONTAINERID"="MI8527"."CONTAINERID"(+))
       filter("MI8527"."TXNDATE"(+)>="TO8080"."TXNDATE")
  29 - access("TI8080"."CONTAINERID"="TO8080"."CONTAINERID"(+))
       filter("TO8080"."TXNDATE"(+)>="TI8080"."TXNDATE")
  30 - filter("TI8080"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID AND "TI8080"."CONTAINERNAME" NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND 
              "TI8080"."CONTAINERNAME" IS NOT NULL AND TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TI8080"."TXNDATE"))>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!-7))
  40 - filter("C"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID)
  41 - access("TI"."CONTAINERID"="C"."CONTAINERID")
  42 - access("C"."PRODUCTID"="P"."PRODUCTID")
  43 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="HML"."HISTORYID")
  44 - filter("HML"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "HML"."SPECNAME"='8080_STAB_BAKE_1_FT' AND 
              "HML"."CDONAME"='TrackOutLot')
  53 - filter("C"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID)
  54 - access("TI"."CONTAINERID"="C"."CONTAINERID")
  56 - access("C"."PRODUCTID"="P"."PRODUCTID")
  57 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="HML"."HISTORYID")
  58 - filter("HML"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "HML"."SPECNAME"='8527_STAGE_BAKE_FT' AND 
              "HML"."CDONAME"='MoveInLot' AND ("HML"."CALLBYCDONAME"='TestWIPMain' OR "HML"."CALLBYCDONAME"='TestWIPMoveNonStd'))
  61 - access("WL"."WIPTRACKIGGROUPKEYID"="HML"."WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID" AND "C"."CONTAINERID"="WL"."CONTAINERID")
  68 - filter("C"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID)
  69 - access("TI"."CONTAINERID"="C"."CONTAINERID")
  71 - access("C"."PRODUCTID"="P"."PRODUCTID")
  72 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="HML"."HISTORYID")
  73 - filter("HML"."WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID" IS NOT NULL AND "HML"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND 
              "HML"."SPECNAME"='8925_2ND_RM_TST_SOT_2_FT' AND "HML"."CDONAME"='CreateFirstInsertion' AND 
              ("HML"."CALLBYCDONAME"='LotMoveOut' OR "HML"."CALLBYCDONAME"='MoveLot' OR 
              "HML"."CALLBYCDONAME"='TestWIPMoveNonStd'))
  79 - filter("WL"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "WL"."SPECNAME"='8925_2ND_RM_TST_SOT_2_FT' AND 
              "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" IS NOT NULL)
  80 - filter("WL"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "WL"."SPECNAME"='8925_2ND_RM_TST_SOT_2_FT' AND 
              "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" IS NOT NULL)
  91 - filter("WL"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "WL"."SPECNAME"='8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT' AND 
              "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" IS NOT NULL)
  92 - filter("WL"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "WL"."SPECNAME"='8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT' AND 
              "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND "WL"."CONTAINERNAME" IS NOT NULL)
  93 - filter("C"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID)
  94 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="WL"."CONTAINERID")
  95 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="HML"."HISTORYID")
  96 - filter("HML"."WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID" IS NOT NULL AND "HML"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND 
              "HML"."SPECNAME"='8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT' AND "HML"."CDONAME"='TrackInLot' AND 
              "WL"."WIPTRACKIGGROUPKEYID"="HML"."WIPTRACKINGGROUPKEYID")
 105 - filter("C"."CONTAINERNAME" LIKE :LOTID)
 106 - access("TI"."CONTAINERID"="C"."CONTAINERID")
 107 - access("C"."PRODUCTID"="P"."PRODUCTID")
 108 - access("C"."CONTAINERID"="HML"."HISTORYID")
 109 - filter("HML"."WORKFLOWNAME"='6_2B2R-DP_WIP' AND "HML"."SPECNAME"='8090_2ND_BAKE_IN_OVEN_SOT_FT' AND 
              "HML"."CDONAME"='TrackOutLot')
```

Comment: The stats suggest that Oracle thinks most of your tables contain only 1 row.  Is that really so or do you need to gather some proper stats for Oracle to work from?

Comment: Hello Tony, the query actually returns 10 rows and it takes me 11 seconds just for these rows to show up.

Comment: One suggestion, try using sqlfiddle.com or any other alternative if there is one for these kind of questions. If you supplied sqlfiddle with all tables created you would get an answer sooner.

Comment: thanks brhneser. I'll try to get back with a better question.

Comment: I suggest that you gather the statistics for the tables being used in the query, then update your question with an updated execution plan. There's a good chance Oracle will generate a better execution plan after you have gathered the stats and the query might run fast just because of the stats. Try it, then let us know of the outcome.

As for generating the stats: See the dbms_stats.gather_table_stats() procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nearly all of the table have only one row. In that case a full table scan would be faster. You can achieve this by specifying the FULL hint.

Comment: hey steve. I'd like to know how can this be done. I am pretty much new to Oracle. thank you so much.

Comment: The oracle documentation is your friend http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm and of course google.